# Select unavailable on TableCellCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

EDIT: I now realize my code below does not make much sense, but am leaving it as is to preserve the question.  My answer below shows my final, correct code for what I was trying to achieve.

I'm attempting to modify some cells in a row on a `GridView` in an `OnRowDataBound` event handler with a `Select` call:

```
e.Row.Cells.AsParallel().Select(c => c.Font.Bold = true);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
'System.Linq.ParallelQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Select'and no 
extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Linq.ParallelQuery' could be found (are you missing a using
 directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have a `using` directive for Linq (`using System.Linq;`), and if I have another object of `IEnumerable` type, the `Select` method is found on it without error:

```
IEnumerable<string> test;
test.Select(s => s);
```

(obviously the above test code would throw an exception, but the point is that it compiles properly)

Why am I unable to call `Select` on a `TableCellCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`TableCellCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not implement generic interface `IEnumerable<T>`. It implements `IEnumerable` which is not generic.Since you are using `AsParallel` on an `IEnumerable` it uses [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237(v=vs.100).aspx) which returns an `IEnumerable`. That's why you can't use `Select` on it. If you wanna get an enumerable of table cells you can cast them:

```
e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().AsParallel()
```

This will use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413602(v=vs.100).aspx) for `IEnumerable<T>` and returns `ParallelQuery<TSource>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`. And you will be able to use `Select` or other LINQ methods on the result.

Comment: Thanks, the `Cast` call was exactly what I needed.  I also second the fact that my code didn't make a whole lot of sense. For the sake of brevity, I've also posted an answer to this question showing my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking Selman22's answer correct since he solved my actual problem, regardless of my troubled code.
I just wanted to also provide my final solution for brevity sake.

As mentioned by Selman22, I did need to do a `Cast<TableCell>()` call first prior to being able to access the LINQ methods.

Additionally, my original line of code doesn't make a lot of sense, as I clearly wasn't paying much attention to what I was doing.
Here is my working code now:

```
e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().Where(c => c.Font.Bold == true).ToList().ForEach(c => c.ForeColor = Color.Red);
```